# Recovering lost files after git pull

Tags: git, github

I added some old assignments to my GitHub. I added one assignment from my local repo to the remote successfully, but made the mistake of adding a `README.md` to it on my web browser. This caused me to not be able to push any commits locally anymore because

```
Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
(e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

So I did a `git pull origin master` command to get that `README.md` file from GitHub, but I believe when it merged with my local branch, it deleted all of my local files that I had not pushed yet. Now all of my other assignments are just empty folders. How do I get these files back? And what would have been the better alternative to pulling from the remote repository?

Comment: Does `git show-ref` give you any clues? Look for a `ref/stash` or a branch in `ref/head/...` you didnt expect to have there

Comment: @krikkan I am getting refs/heads/master and refs/remotes/origin/master

Comment: Are you sure you had committed the files?

Comment: @krikkan I initialized the git repo in a directory with the files, but never committed them or pushed them. Does that mean I can not recover them?

Comment: I do not know what could have happened. Did you check your trash folder? Also, what do you get if you do `git log`? finally, after initializing the repo locally, did you push the initial commit?

Comment: @krikkan idk what happened either, but I should have the files backed up on a drive somehwere. I only committed/pushed one of the several assignments I had. The rest I didn't touch after initializing the repo. Then after doing a couple commits and pushes to the one assignment, and pulling it from the remote, I noticed in finder that all the other assignment folders were empty. I'm pretty new to git and was trying to get used to it, but now my working tree is just so messed up

Comment: `git pull` alone should not discard files from disk. You may have the `autostash` option turned on : check `git stash list` to see if something was stashed away.

Comment: @LeGEC "git pull alone should not discard files from disk" Why not? If a file was deleted on the remote and not edited locally, isn't that _exactly_ what we would expect to happen? There is only one change, deletion, and a merge enacts that change. And git pull, by default, does a merge.

Comment: @matt: You are right : the result of the merge can indicate "this file needs to be deleted". I meant : from the actions the OP mentions, he should be only merging an added `README.md` file, and if such is the case, `git pull` alone should not have deleted the other files. Perhaps the OP added the file in such a way that gitlab understood "create a commit where you delete everything else" ; I'd be surprised, but it could be a possibility.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. To the extent that a readme was added at the remote end and this made it impossible to push, this is a well-handled issue, a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate, and should be marked as such. The problem is that the _other_ stuff the OP says is just hand-waving: "I believe when it merged with my local branch, it deleted all of my local files that I had not pushed yet." We don't even have a clear statement of what really happened. We don't even know what branch the OP was on to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get these files back

Actions performed with git are undoable only to the extent that there is a *commit* reflecting the state you want to get back to. Only a commit is a "thing" in git.

So, if you did a `git pull` and it had effects you don't like, you can `git reset` back to the commit before you did the pull.

But if your action affected files that were *not* committed, then there is absolutely nothing you can do. Files that are not committed are no concern of git's.

Comment: So initializing a repo in a directory does not automatically commit everything in the directory?

Comment: @HunterSwag Correct. Not much happens "automatically" with git. Initializing a repo merely says "I'd like to start using git here, please.". To commit, you still have to do what you would ordinarily do: having said `git init`, you then say `git add .` (to configure the commit) and then `git commit -m'Message'` (to make the commit).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get file `README.md` at local. Because this file **never staged** to local repository.

You can get file `README.md` at GitHub.com easily, because you just saved it, it has a commit hash string.

Answer (score 0):

You can ur files back in GIT > Shelf , if you're using Intellij its easy to find ur uncommitted changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).