# Git pull Cause files not added to disappear

Tags: git

I git add is not executed before git pull

`git pull origin master`

the files that are not added will disappear.

How to recover them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering lost files after git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908606/recovering-lost-files-after-git-pull)

Answer (score 0):

To restore, check the [reflog](https://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html). It may be that you can't recover as not added before pull. However if not and it helps, reset to the revision of your wish.

---

In the future you can configure to rebase on pull and automatically stash while rebasing so to keep local uncommitted changes:

```
$ git config pull.rebase true
$ git config rebase.autoStash true
```

Please find the detailed documentation for `git-pull(1)` online here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull